# How to write single post service in Angular and call it dynamically multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular5, observable

Below are two different get calls but I want to create only one.

```
getDashBoardDetails(userId): Observable<DashboardTo> {
    let keys = this.crmBaseUrl + apiCall.gnGetDashBoardDetails + "?createdBy=" + userId;;
    //let keys = apiCall.organisationMaster2;
    return this.http
        .get(keys)
        .map((res: Response) => res)
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || "Server error"));
}

getDealerDashBoardDetails(): Observable<DealerDashboardTo> {
    let keys = this.crmBaseUrl + apiCall.gnGetDealerDashBoardDetails
    return this.http
        .get(keys)
        .map((res: Response) => res)
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || "Server error"));
}
```

Comment: need to add more detail to it like your objective etc.

Comment: If what you want is get data from two different endpoints in the same http call, you can try with forkjoin or zip operator. I suggest you also migrate your code to the new httpClient ( no need to map the response ). Let me know if this is what you want and I can provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply like this :

```
getDashBoardDetails(userId): Observable < DashboardTo > {
    let keys = this.crmBaseUrl + apiCall.gnGetDashBoardDetails + "?createdBy=" + userId;
    this.makeCall(keys).subscribe(res => ... )
}

getDealerDashBoardDetails(): Observable < DealerDashboardTo > {
    let keys = this.crmBaseUrl + apiCall.gnGetDealerDashBoardDetails;
    this.makeCall(keys).subscribe(res => ... )
}

makeCall(keys){
    return this.http
        .get(keys)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json() ) // should be res.json(), not res
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || "Server error"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create an interface named `IDashboard` and implement that interface in `DealerDashboardTo` and `DashboardTo`

Then just create this method as such:

```
getDetails(userId?): Observable<IDashboard> {
  let urlEnd = userId ? `${apiCall.gnGetDashBoardDetails}?createdBy=${userId}` : apiCall.gnGetDealerDashBoardDetails;
  let keys = this.crmBaseUrl + urlEnd;
  return this.http
    .get<IDashboard>(keys)
    .map((res: Response) => res)
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || "Server error"));
}
```

I'm sure this isn't a complete answer. But that's the best I can do with the info you've provided.

Also, not sure why you're doing a `.map` on `.get`

Comment: Yes, it should be `.map(res => res.json())`

Comment: But isn't that something that we're assuming? He didn't write the constructor in the provided code.

Comment: No, it's standard Angular stuff. We're transforming a Response into JSON.

Comment: Or it could be understood as `.map` returns an Observable that wraps a res. You're definitely assuming.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your exact objective , but I am assuming either of the below approaches will help you

```
let keys1 = this.crmBaseUrl + apiCall.gnGetDashBoardDetails + "?createdBy=" + userId;;
 let keys2 = this.crmBaseUrl + apiCall.gnGetDealerDashBoardDetails

    forkJoin([keys1, keys2]).subscribe(results => {

       var keys1Result = results[0];
     var keys2Result = results[1];

    });
```

Or create a reusable method by accepting an parameter Url

```
getDashboardDetails(url:string){
          return this.http
        .get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => res)
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || "Server error"));
}
```